# Use EnumType.None, or Nullable<EnumType>?

Tags: c#, enums, nullable, object-model

Enums are generally used to define the state of a particular property of a class, say in an object model of some sort. For some of these properties, the state 'this property is not set' is valid.

In these situations, should I use a zero `None` enum value, or make the property type nullable?

```
public MyEnum Property { get; set; }

public enum MyEnum {
    None = 0,
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

or

```
public MyEnum? Property { get; set; }

public enum MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `MyEnum.None` - it is much more expressive, or even `MyEnum.Invalid` to convey meaning.

You can also set it to other values than 0 - since it is based on int, you can set it to be -1 and the first valid value to 1:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    InvalidValue = -1,
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2
}
```

In your code you can easily check for this value being passed in and throw a descriptive exception.

A nullable enum type is not expected and less expressive. It requires users of you code to be aware of this and check for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this conclusively, a lot of factors in your app will influence this. I tend to just define the enum value to 0, but not specify a zero value in the enum.

```
enum Foo 
{
   A = 1,
   B = 2
}

...

Foo myFoo = (Foo)0;
```

This gives the benefit of a sentinel value, without polluting the enum.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "None" value instead of a nullable enum. If nothing else, to me `if(Property == MyEnum.None)` is a lot more readable than `if(Property == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the first value to 1, since it will be initally 0.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2
}
```

I think both of your situations are acceptable! It will depend upon your situation. When working with a user interface your first example with the 'None' value will *probbaly* be easier to use. However, the Nullable gives more information about how the variable should be used.